# compressed file IO in c++

Tags: c++, compression, vtk

I have a simulation in which I need to dump large amount of data, usually on the order ~50GB or so, while the code is running, which usually happens on the order of weeks. Right now, I am  exporting the data as `legacy ASCII VTK` files.

I was wondering if there is any way to compress the data as it is being written to the disk so I can save some space (I need to run multiple versions of the code at the same time). I prefer something from the standard library if possible.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into zlib, http://zlib.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can use boost, look at the zlib filter [compressor and decompressor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/zlib.html#examples)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>

int main() 
{
    using namespace std;

    ifstream file("hello.z", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
    filtering_streambuf<input> in;
    in.push(zlib_decompressor());
    in.push(file);
    boost::iostreams::copy(in, cout);
}
```

Comment: If you don't use Boost, still check out zlib. It's very easy to use. Short of that, I could write up an adaptive huffman encoder/decoder right in Stack Overflow, it's not too hard. That would only use the standard library :-D